# File uploading using sdk3?

Tags: flex3, upload

How do I upload files using sdk3? I'm developing my project using flex and spring
iam using the jboss server

Comment: Please add more detail. What version of spring are you using?

Comment: did you implement the file upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the flex side you will have to create a FileReference object and use the upload method to upload the file. The upload method requires a Request object which is the URL of your Spring controller that is going to handle your upload.

On the server side, you can have a CommonsMultipartResolver and since you will not be using spring beans.. you will have to get the file from request using something like this:

```
 MultipartActionRequest multipartRequest = (MultipartActionRequest) request;
 MultipartFile multipartFile = multipartRequest.getFile("file");
```

Hope this helps,
Regards,
Abdel Raoof

Comment: In addition you can have a look at the FileReference documentation for coding details: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=17_Networking_and_communications_7.html